# How to stream rtmp in angular 6 or in HTML 5

Tags: html, node.js, angular, rtmp

I have integrated rtmp with node server now i need to show rtmp stream in my angular 6 app as live video. Any suggestion for me?

I have tried vidojs and other player but that did not worked for me.

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type="video/webm" />
 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
```

Comment: if you are giving negative voting then plz explain why?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but my assumption would be; no examples of what you've tried. No real "question" in an experiment you've ran. Just a "how do I do this?" question is usually not enough to get proper help.

If there was a question with VideoJS and some example code you wrote or tried, you may have different tags and the question would be more "relevant". You're now just asking other to do your job basically and that's sort off frowned upon I presume.

Comment: i will share code soon

Comment: hi @yogeshchavan have you found solution?

Comment: not yet, i was doing R & D and now im switched to other task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream needs to be delivered in format that can be played on HTML5 (HLS, MPEG DASH, WebRTC). 
If stream is H264+AAC can be delivered using Wowza SE as HLS to Safari, DASH to Chrome/Firefox (adaptive playback is required depending on browser)

You can try this technology in this demo that should play HLS in Safari and DASH in Chrome:
https://videonow.live/channel/videonowlive/

If using different codecs or want to publish as WebRTC, transcoding will also be required.
For further research, deploy this free open source WP plugin for running these capabilities on your own setup:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/videowhisper-live-streaming-integration/

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers do not support rtmp without flash. You must convert to a format it does support like DASH, and use a player like video.js

Comment: Can you give any reference or example to achieve above  suggestion

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webcam

The one component gives you full control and lets you take snapshots via actions and event bindings

Comment: currently I'm switched to another project but will try this ASAP. thanks for your help.